# redirecting error messages in a bash script

Tags: bash, pbs

I'm using a server with PBS. I'm testing it with

```
echo sleep 10 | qsub
```

At the moment there is a problem with the server and an error message is returned. By redirecting this error message

```
echo sleep 10 | qsub 2>&1
```

nothing will be printed.

Now I would like to put this into a shell script and save the output in a variable:

```
out=`echo sleep 10 | qsub 2>&1`
```

However, although I'm redirecting the error message using `2>&1`, the variable `out` still contains the error message. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`2>&1` - This actually redirects STDERR to STDOUT

What you're after is `2>/dev/null`

```
out=`echo sleep 10 | qsub 2>/dev/null`
```